# Reclassify variable in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, modelbuilder

I want to reclassify a raster (variable) in model builder in two classes. First class ist 0-treshold = NoData and second is treshold-max value = 1. It works fine if i use an existing raster file as input (where i can state and know the max value) but not for variables in ModelBuilder.

Any ideas how to do it in ModelBuilder, or with ArcPy?

[image: This is my model in modelbuilder]

**EDIT:**

Here is my edited model, but it's not running yet.

[image: Edited model in modelbuilder]

Comment: Please provide some code or a screenshot of your model...

Comment: You're right, sorry for that. Model is attached now

Comment: There is a spelling error in the expression. The function name should be apply_threshold instead of apply _treshold. The name in the expression should match what is in the code block.

Comment: Ah that was obvious. Sorry for that stupid mistake and thanks for your reply. I corrected the spelling mistakes, but it is still not running. As soon as I connect the threshold Parameter and the rcls_flow_path as precondition (both data type any value, maybe here is the mistake?), the calculate value field can't be run anymore. Whats exactly the purpose of rcls_flow_path?

Comment: rcls_flow_path is a full path to where you want to save the reclassed flow accumulation raster

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by full path, but I really appreciate your help. Is there anything, that I did wrong in the model that causes it not to run? Even if I build that specific part in a new model, it doesn't work. As soon as I connect the threshold and rcls_flow_path variables, it turns "white" and is not able to run anymore. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Fullpath can be something like rcls_flow_path  = c:\temp\tempdata.gdb\flow_acc_reclassed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Replace your reclassify step with the following steps:

- Use the [Get Raster Properties](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/get-raster-properties.htm) tool to retrieve the **maximum** value from your flow accummulation raster.
- Use the [Calculate Value](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/calculate-value.htm) tool and a **python snippet** to reclassify your flow accumulation raster.
- Set the **Data Type** of the Calculate Value tool to "**Raster Layer**"
- Define the following function in the code block

  ```
  def apply_threshold(flow_acc, max_flow,threshold, rcls_flow_path):
       rcls = arcpy.sa.Reclassify(flow_acc,"Value","0 {0} NODATA; {0} {1} 1".format(threshold,max_flow), "DATA")
       rcls.save(rcls_flow_path)
       return rcls_flow_path
  ```

The function defined above accepts a flow accummulation raster, max flow value, a threshold and an output path. Values 0 - threshold are reclassed to NODATA and values from threshold to max value are reclassed to 1.

See sample model below.
[image]

- Connect the reclassed flow accumulation to the rest of your model....

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I got the raster properties, I filled in the Expression and Code Block field as said, but how can I connect the max_flow and other parameters to the model?

Comment: Connect  them as preconditions to Calculate  Tool.